# How to remove quote (') from the my scraped output

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can i get rid of the quotes in the output. I have tried to used `.strip('')` but the output does not seem to change.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIFTY_50')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
niftylist_raw = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})

nifty_symbol =[]

for row in niftylist_raw.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    nifty_symbols = row.findAll('td')[1].text


    nifty_symbol.append(nifty_symbols.strip(''))
print(nifty_symbol)
```

The current output looks like this:

> ['ADANIPORTS.NS\n', 'ASIANPAINT.NS', 'AXISBANK.NS', 'BAJAJ-AUTO.NS',
>   'BAJFINANCE.NS', 'BAJAJFINSV.NS', 'BHARTIARTL.NS', 'INFRATEL.NS',
>   'BPCL.NS', 'CIPLA.NS', 'COALINDIA.NS', 'DRREDDY.NS', 'EICHERMOT.NS',
>   'GAIL.NS', 'GRASIM.NS', 'HCLTECH.NS', 'HDFC.NS', 'HDFCBANK.NS',
>   'HEROMOTOCO.NS', 'HINDALCO.NS', 'HINDUNILVR.NS', 'BRITANNIA.NS',
>   'ICICIBANK.NS', 'INDUSINDBK.NS', 'INFY.NS', 'IOC.NS', 'ITC.NS',
>   'JSWSTEEL.NS', 'KOTAKBANK.NS', 'LT.NS', 'M&M.NS', 'MARUTI.NS',
>   'NESTLEIND.NS', 'NTPC.NS', 'ONGC.NS', 'POWERGRID.NS', 'RELIANCE.NS',
>   'SBIN.NS', 'SUNPHARMA.NS', 'TCS.NS', 'TATAMOTORS.NS', 'TATASTEEL.NS',
>   'TECHM.NS', 'TITAN.NS', 'ULTRACEMCO.NS', 'UPL.NS', 'VEDL.NS',
>   'WIPRO.NS', 'YESBANK.NS', 'ZEEL.NS']

I would like to remove the upper quotes. This is because the exported file also has the quote.

I can just convert this to `df = pd.Dataframe(nifty_symbol)` which would solve the problem but I still want to learn how I could have used the .strip function.
Any help would be helpful. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no actual quotes in the list of strings. The single quotes surrounding each element are put there by python to let you know it is a string, as opposed to some other datatype. If you print each element individually, or store it in a file, you will not see the quotes.

Comment: i had exported this to a text file and there quotes were ('') were there just like how it appears in the output.

Comment: Can I see how you exported the text? When i do `with open("test.txt", "w") as test_file: test_file.writelines(nifty_symbol)` I don't get any quotes.

Comment: i added the following code: twitter = []
for thesymbol in nifty_symbol:
    twitter.append(thesymbol[:-3])


and text file contains : 

['ADANIPORTS.', 'ASIANPAINT', 'AXISBANK', 'BAJAJ-AUTO', 'BAJFINANCE', 'BAJAJFINSV', 'BHARTIARTL', 'INFRATEL', 'BPCL', 'CIPLA', 'COALINDIA', 'DRREDDY', 'EICHERMOT', 'GAIL', 'GRASIM', 'HCLTECH', 'HDFC', 'HDFCBANK', 'HEROMOTOCO', 'HINDALCO', 'HINDUNILVR', 'BRITANNIA', 'ICICIBANK', 'INDUSINDBK', 'INFY', 'IOC', 'ITC', 'JSWSTEEL', 'KOTAKBANK', 'LT', 'M&M', 'MARUTI', 'TATASTEEL', 'TECHM', 'TITAN', 'ULTRACEMCO', 'UPL', 'VEDL', 'WIPRO', 'YESBANK', 'ZEEL']

Comment: the `twitter` variable is not a text file. It's a python list. By text file, I mean some bytes actually written out to disk, like "my_data.txt". My prior point still stands. Python will show strings surrounded with single quotes, that does not mean the literal character `'` is in the string.